# Escape quotes in a String in Java

Tags: java

I have the below string in which I am successfully escaping the quotes with .

```
        <Test sample=\"5\" couponCode=\"\"><WeatherApp>"
        + "<Temp><UpdateInfo><WeatherDetail>"
        + "<Release batchNo=\"\"/>"
        + "</WeatherDetail></UpdateInfo></Temp>"    
        + "</WeatherApp></Test>
```

My question is, lets say I want to replace one of the values in this string with my DTO.getVal(), how do I do it?

For eg -

```
        <Test sample="dto.getVal()" couponCode=\"\"><WeatherApp>"
        + "<Temp><UpdateInfo><WeatherDetail>"
        + "<Release batchNo=\"\"/>"
        + "</WeatherDetail></UpdateInfo></Temp>"    
        + "</WeatherApp></Test>
```

I have done this multiple ways, and haven't been successful so far. Can you please advise?

Comment: use + to concatenate Strings an variables.

Comment: Do this: sample=" + dto.getVal() + " coupon

Comment: <Test sample=\"" + dto.getVal() + "\" couponCode=\"\"><WeatherApp>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <Test sample=\""+dto.getVal()+"\" couponCode=\"\"><WeatherApp>"
        + "<Temp><UpdateInfo><WeatherDetail>"
       + "<Release batchNo=\"\"/>"
       + "</WeatherDetail></UpdateInfo></Temp>"    
        + "</WeatherApp></Test>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use String concatenation: `\"" + dto.getVal() + "\"`